# Spring SAML2 throws Issuer in Request is invalid

Tags: spring, weblogic, saml

I have been able to deploy the SPRING SAML sample application correctly on weblogic 12C. I followed the [Spring SAML on Weblogic 12c][1].

On load of the page I select option  http://idp.ssocircle.com and click on Start Single Sign on.

This does not bring the login page correctly. But shows an error . Though I tried the same on tomcat server where it works fine.

**

> Error occurred Reason: Issuer in Request is invalid.

**

as 
with URL - https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/ssocircle?SAMLRequest=nVLLbsIwEPyVyPe8IChgkSBahIpEVURCD70ZsxBXjp16HdT%2BfR0eLb1w6MXS2rMzuzMeTz5r6R3BoNAqI3EQEQ8U1zuhDhnZlHN%2FSCb5GFktew2dtrZSa%2FhoAa3nGhXS80tGWqOoZiiQKlYDUstpMX1e0l4Q0cZoq7mWxJsigrFO6lErbGswBZij4LBZLzNSWdvQMJSaM1lptHQYRf0QG%2BNm8RF4a4T98k%2BC3dlICLsiLIoX4s3cSEIxe1qjY0JHJXZNgKi5MFxCwHVNk8Qxou561rATBrgNa7BsKgXD8AdLvLk2HE77ZmTPJLqrxSwjLB7tt8D2EEEi4neI04SLUdpPD9Ww2lcOhCuGKI7w24bYwkKhZcpmpBfFAz9K%2FXhURintJ3TQC%2Frx6I14q4tLD0Kd3b9n6fYMQvpUlit%2F9VKUxHu9pugA5JIZPamb27DuE7NrQiT%2Fbx6dnztm2Ti8HSG%2FlH9%2FUf4N&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&Signature=AYbCt8tqpWS2RWOC23Hrhkan%2Bs%2FS8U%2BZt9%2FeTn6z9a4900ikBXC9ivCft7P%2FOLGqEbMiDbBhPrUvqxLn44A%2Fx0CkHgH2%2BtmE6MIpyX%2FdD7ipCxbyX49sLTcGq7lmtvV25MqlCqvbIwOr1iqbPrnsxppHjIGMzXJBD8D%2BKsOtoxE2H7hkcZtk%2FeuXCmGswfZwr74uyh0lpt8pw1%2FQut3c%2BbDZP3E5oOSa4ajzBFAzLB%2FEpWFM%2F92ulmOgKTjDJRjWLWKXiXsNgWRdjVqbbcTxbYbhvvpUtk9uikvzy1%2BU%2FgFf%2FP0DY3eafWzmjte9Vs4%2FSsLyU%2BAz0yM69BMcsdO85g%3D%3D

Comment: Just one more note - I am running within a oracle virtual box, and it has problem in tomcat as well. So it seems due to the application being run within the VM - its throwing this error.

Comment: Have you tried running the sample directly on a machine?  The sample comes bundled with configuration for running an embedded Tomcat instance so you can simply run `mvn clean tomcat7:run` to start a Tomcat instance and access the sample on [http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample](http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample).

Answer (score 0):

I tried running on the machine and it works fine. I realized that from the VM the auto register of the services was not working.

Hence I registered the metadata and it started working fine.